Map bpy Object to USD prim during export?
Is there any way to map a bpy Object to a USD prim in the python USDHook?
I tried by name which worked for awhile until I hit/discovered both "." and "-" bpy object names are mapped to "_" in prim names. Which means mapping back is impossible reliably.
There seems to be some hooks added with USDHook but that only provides the material mapping.
I'm aware I could just write my own exporter.
